# Get DOM element after model update in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

New to angular. I am trying to get a DOM element after the model has been updated, but I get null. Here's my HTML code.

```
<div ng-repeat="file in files">
 <span id="file{{file.id}}">{{file.name}}</span>
 <canvas id="canvas{{file.id}}" />
</div>
```

Here's my controller code

```
angular.module('mycontrollers',[])
 .controller('FileController',function(FileService) {
       $scope.files = {};
    FileService.updateFiles()
        .then(
        function(data) {
            $scope.files = data.files;
            updateCanvas($scope.files);
        },function(err) {
            console.log("error occured");
        };
 };
function updateCanvas(files) {
    files.forEach(function(file){
    var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas'+file.id);
    ... 
    do something with canvas
    ...
    }
}
```

The canvas is null as document.getElementById doesn't find the element. The response from the server returns correctly (hence I have not added the FileService code). data.files contains appropriate data.

How can I get the element after model has been updated?

Comment: are you getting any error in console ? and is response from server is coming correctly ?

Comment: The error is that 'canvas' variable is null as I am guessing the model (and hence the DOM) has not been updated yet, when I call updateCanvas. The response from the server contains the correct data.

Answer (score 2):

That's because the model has been updated but the DOM still hasn't.

What you can do is call your `updateCanvas` function with a timeout, which will make sure the function will run after the DOM is updated:

```
.controller('FileController',function(FileService, $timeout) {
    ....
    $timeout(function() { updateCanvas($scope.files) });
```

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using directive for this kind DOM manipulation, instead of direct doing DOM manipulation using ids.

here's working example:

http://jsfiddle.net/jigardafda/1ou63cgf/2/

HTML

```
<div ng-app="app">
    <div ng-controller="tcrtl">
        <div ng-repeat="file in files">
            <span>{{file.name}}</span>
            <my-canvas conf="file"></my-canvas>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);
app
    .service('FileService', function($q){
        // Mocked service 
        var files = [
            {
                name: "ONE",
                id: 'one'
            },
            {
                name: "TWO",
                id: 'two'
            }
        ]

        this.updateFiles = function(){
            var deferred = $q.defer();
            deferred.resolve({
                files: files
            });
            return deferred.promise;
        };

    })
    .directive('myCanvas', function(){
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            template: "<canvas id='{{conf.id}}' />",
            scope: {
                conf: '='
            },
            controller: function(){
                // Do something 
            },
            link: function(scope, ele, attr){
                var c = ele[0].querySelector("canvas");
                var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
                ctx.fillStyle = "#FF0000";
                ctx.fillRect(0,0,150,75);
            }
        }
    })
    .controller('tcrtl',function($scope, FileService) {
        $scope.files = {};
        FileService.updateFiles().then(
            function(data) {
                $scope.files = data.files;
            },function(err) {
                console.log("error occured");
            });
    });
```